# S3 AWS Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$content-type", "audio/wav"]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to uploading objects to S3 using presigned URLs

Here is my python code: (refer from this post: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html)

```
import json

URL = "https://exmaple.server-give-me-presigned-URLs"
r = requests.get(url = URL)

response = r.json()
print("debug type payload: ", type(response))
print("debug key: ", response.keys())
print("debug value: ", response["jsonresult"])
print("debug ", response["signedupload"]["fields"])
print("debug ", response["signedupload"]["url"])
print("url type ", type(response["signedupload"]["url"]))

with open("test-wav-file.wav", 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': ("/test-wav-file.wav", f)}
    http_response = requests.post(response["signedupload"]["url"], data=response["signedupload"]["fields"], files=files)

print("File upload HTTP: ", http_response.text)
```

I got the error when run:

```
('File upload HTTP: ', u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$content-type", "audio/wav"]</Message><RequestId>1TRNC1XPX4MCJPN6</RequestId><HostId>h/YdSUDuPeZhUU1TqAu1BZrCfyXKiNTYvisbvp3iaLcoLoriQPREnJI1LZp69hDE4kOWYSVog7A=</HostId></Error>')
```

But when I change  header content-type to `headers = {'Content-type': 'audio/wav'}`
I got the error:

```
('File upload HTTP: ', u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>PreconditionFailed</Code><Message>At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold</Message><Condition>Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data</Condition><RequestId>S86QYFG0AYTY26WQ</RequestId><HostId>lvxNkydNcuiwE/UVZY2xRMBoqk/BSUn7qathgXWSu3Fii8ZlVlKDkEjOotw4fmU3bfFgjYbsspE=</HostId></Error>')
```

So do we have any kind of content-type satisfy all condition? Please help me

Many thanks

Comment: What conditions did you set on the url? You haven't show your code how exactly did you generate your pre-signed url.

Comment: I'm not the people who generate the pre-signed url, I just call to the server and they give me all needed information for upload to they S3.

Comment: So you have to ask who ever generates these urls what conditions you must satisify.

Comment: The payload should be `"signedupload": {
    "url": "https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxx",
    "fields": {
      "acl": "private",
      "key": "asd/rs9_xxxx.wav",
      "x-amz-algorithm": "xx",
      "x-amz-credential": "xxxx_request",
      "x-amz-date": "20010355Z",
      "x-amz-security-token": "xS2R",
      "policy": "exxxx9XX0=",
      "x-amz-signature": "xxxfb00a922"
    }
  }`

Comment: ok thanks @Marcin very much, I will try to tell them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem:

just add 2 fields `"content-type": "audio/wav"` and `"x-amz-meta-tag": ""` in the payload and it work :D

`x-amz-meta-tag` can be any value.

Hope to help someone like me